# Replace old ASMX service with modern AJAX

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net, asmx

I have some legacy code where:

1. ASP .NET page sends request using proxy to ASMX
2. Before sending request, I manually (in JavaScript) pack all necessary data into structures required by proxy
3. From time to time I get random InvalidOperationException when executing that service

As a result, I would like to get rid of asmx mechanism.

What I would like to do, is take advantage of jQuery and just simply POST JSONed data to ASP .NET .... But, where should I post it, to aspx page? What are the approaches in ASP .NET 2.0? Provided I'm using jQuery, how should the server side look? Do I have to anyway create aspx file as request entry point and code behind class (that inherits from **Page**) with logic?

Thanks,Pawel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [use WCF to write a REST Service that uses JSON](http://www.onesadjam.com/2010/05/creating-rest-web-service-using-wcf-and.html).

Answer (score 0):

ASMX has nothing wrong at all, those are web services and are not supposed to return InvalidOperationException when properly designed and used.

you can have a look at what page methods are, basically you add a scriptmanager to the page and some attributes and you can then call these methods inside the aspx ( code behind ) as if they were on a web service, those methods are static so you cannot access controls and the page instance from there but usually this is not a problem and you can do all you need if you have a good design.

The way you invoke those page methods is with client side JS with or without jQuery.

Comment: ASMX has been marked as "legacy" by Microsoft (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t745kdsh.aspx).

Comment: ok, did not know that article thanks! Still even if clearly WCF is far better, a well written xml web service should and does not throw exceptions with no reason.

Comment: Yeah, there must be something wrong with that service - obviously I don't know what. But before start troubleshooting it, I would like to replace it with something new (if possible). Thanks